# How to get all the routes in an adonis jakefile?

Tags: node.js, laravel, adonis.js

I am tring to write a jakefile in adonis framework, which can iterate over all the routes defined in routes.js file.

I am not sure, if the command adonis route:list can be used in any way in the jakefile itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `adonis route:list` in your Jakefile using `jake.exec` or `jake.createExec`

```
var ex = jake.createExec(['adonis', 'route:list']);

ex.addListener('stdout', (msg, code) => console.log(msg));
```

`jake.exec` documentation: https://jakejs.com/#running-shell-commands-jake-exec-and-jake-createexec-

The `route:list` command is defined in https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-cli/blob/develop/src/Commands/RouteList/index.js. Browsing this file could help you understand how it achieves this action.

Comment: it works, but my need is to iterate over the routes so found in the list, Is there a way to get that done.

Comment: You can split the output using `msg.split('\n')` and process each route individually.

Comment: <Buffer e2 94 8c e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 ac e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 80 e2 94 ... 632 more bytes>
The response of message is something like this
on executing
var ex = jake.createExec(['adonis route:list'])
ex.addListener('stdout', function (msg, code) {
   console.log(msg)
});
ex.run();

Comment: If `msg` is a buffer then you have to fist convert it into a string: `msg.toString('utf8').split('\n')`